# Source for the tradition of buying seats in synagogues

Tags: minhag, synagogue, provenance

In many synagogues, it is common to buy a seat before the new year's day. The price for a seat often serves also as "membership fee" for membership in the synagogue community. When did this tradition begin?

Comment: It's fair to ask when this began but I see no reason to call it a tradition. It's just supply and demand

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gemara in brachos 6 already mentions the importance of having a specific shul to daven in (some meforshim),and to have a specific seat(other meforshim).

The earliest I know of is in teshuvos HaRosh[mid 13th century] in Klal 5 where he discusses Bais Kenesses issues. He has a few simanim where seats are discussed and he mentions the idea of selling seats and handing it over to their children b'yerusha(inheritance).

In Siman 5 a case is discussed concerning Reuvein who's father Yaakov owned a seat and he passed away and left it to his son(Reuvein) .The seat also had the name Yaakov on it(some synogouges still do this today). Shimon comes and claims that the seat belongs to him since his father Yissachor bought it and he showed a shtar(document). The question is basically is Reuvein's chazaka stronger than Shimon's shtar. See it inside for more info.

Text :

**שאלה** ילמדנו רבינו בענין המקומות של בית הכנסת שרגילים בעליהם למשכנם ולמכרם ולהורישם לבניהם והמנהג להיות שם בעל המקום כתוב במקומו ואינו מקפיד לישב שם תדיר אלא כאחד העם והיה לראובן מקום אחד שהיה שם אביו יעקב כתוב בו זה כמה שנים יותר משני חזקה ולאחר פטירת אביו נשאר המקום בחזקת ראובן ועתה בא שמעון והוא מערער על המקום וטוען שהוא של יששכר אביו והוא מראה שטר הקנייה בשם אביו וראובן טוען שכבר החזיק בו מכח אביו יותר משני חזקה לפי שהיה שמו כתוב בו ולא בא שום אדם לערער עליו בחייו ועתה שהוא החזיק בו בתורת ירושה ושמעון טוען שאין כתיבת שם יעקב ראיה (לשני) לשם חזקה ועוד שאינה קרויה חזקה במקומות של בהכ"נ מפני שאינו יכול להביא ראיה על חזקתו.